# Difference Between JBOSS EAP and JBOSS Application Server

Tags: jboss, application-server, jboss-eap-6

Can somebody please explain the difference between JBOSS EAP and JBOSS Application Server in a simple way. I tried to find the diff in multiple sites but I can't, so please help me on this.

Cheers...!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between JBoss EAP, Wildfly, JBoss web, and JBoss server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756933/what-is-the-difference-between-jboss-eap-wildfly-jboss-web-and-jboss-server)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756933/what-is-the-difference-between-jboss-eap-wildfly-jboss-web-and-jboss-server. Though JBoss EAP 7 has been released so there is a supported Java EE 7 version as well.