# Jboss AS 7 work with JDK8

Tags: jboss, java-8, jboss7.x, wildfly-8

I'm trying startup JBoss EAP 7.1.1 Final with JDK 1.8.0_144 in Window 7 enviroment. Each time I run the standalone.bat from command line I got following error. Server halt on starting cannot proceed anymore.

```
09:20:44,413 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
09:20:45,203 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
09:20:45,265 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
```

Below is link i download JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final. I also configure my JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variable, I think configuration should not an issue.

http://jbossas.jboss.org/downloads

I found some article mention that Jboss AS 7 unable work with JDK8 but my colleagues is PC is startup with JDK8. I guess should has another way to work up.

```
AS7.1 does not work on JDK8.
Downgrade to JDK7 or Upgrade AS to WildFly 8.
```

**Update**

After trying, I found Jboss EAP 7.0 or Jboss AS 7.0.0 Final is executable with JDK8, I will downgrade to that version that what I need.

Comment: Honestly, I would have rather gone up to that friend first to inquire if he/she made any specific configuration changes to make it work and then compared why it wouldn't work for me.

Comment: our configuration is same. that's why is a tricky issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to start jboss-as-7.1.1.Final with JDK 8 on Windows 8.1 command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194474/unable-to-start-jboss-as-7-1-1-final-with-jdk-8-on-windows-8-1-command-prompt)

Comment: James R. Perkins, the post recommend use JDK1.7 but my company insist use JDK8.

Answer (score 3):

The article you read is correct, JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final does not work on jdk 8. Only EAP 6.3.3 (which is way newer than 7.1.1) and above have jdk8 support

https://access.redhat.com/articles/111663

Are you sure your friend is using jdk 8? Even if he is using jdk8, it is not recommended to do so.

Comment: Yes. When Jboss server startup. It's show Jboss EAP is 7.0 and JDK is 1.8.

Comment: Ok, EAP 7 is not the same as jboss 7.1.1. EAP is the enterprise version, and eap 7 is based on wildlfy, which supports jdk8. jboss 7.1.1 is community, and older than wildfly

Comment: mendieta, Are you mean EAP is different AS but I tried another jboss-as-7.0.0.Final.zip, it working as well.

Comment: Yes, they are not the same.. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756933/what-is-the-difference-between-jboss-eap-wildfly-jboss-web-and-jboss-server

Answer (score 0):

Go for Wildfly - v8 server it seemlessly works with jdk8