# Can I still use JDK 7 on macOS?

Tags: java, macos, java-7

I need to run an old version of JDK 7 on macOS.

I've looked on 'How do I use JDK 7 on Mac OSX?' in 'JavaVirtualMachines': [How do I use JDK 7 on Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267392/how-do-i-use-jdk-7-on-mac-osx/10358228#10358228)

also looked at: 'OpenJDK': https://openjdk.java.net/

Any idea where to find JDK 7 for macOS please?

Answer (score 0):

You should always keep the latest update of the JDK and JRE as they come with more functionalities and more bug improvements.
You can get JDK7 only through Oracle Support as per Oracle.

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

Thanks

Comment: I always use JDK 13.02 (& 14) wth WildFly 19.0.0. Need JDK 7 for JBoss 7.x. Oracle say: "Java SE 7 - Updates for Java SE 7 released after April 2015 are only available to Oracle Customers through My Oracle Support (requires support login).". I don't have a 'paid contract' with Oracle.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the only way to get JDK 7. JBoss 7 also supports JDK8.

Comment: Thanks ' jsgrewal12' for that. JBoss 7 doesn't appear to run with JDK 8: "The article you read is correct, JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final does not work on jdk 8. Only EAP 6.3.3 (which is way newer than 7.1.1) and above have jdk8 support" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067817/jboss-as-7-work-with-jdk8. I'll investigate again.

Answer (score 0):

Found free version of JDK 7.x from:

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase7-archive-downloads.html